# X11 Forwarding for non-root user not working

Tags: macosx, 18.04, vagrant, x11-forwarding

[Cross-Posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50071150/979315)

### Environmental Details

Relevant bits of server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Relevant bits of client's $HOME/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Using XQuartz on macOS High Sierra.

### The Problem

I'm spinning up a vagrant Ubuntu 18.04 VM. I've added a second user outside of the `vagrant` user.

```
ssh -X vagrant@ubuntu-bionic xclock
```

I can get X11Forwarding to work when I login as the `vagrant` user. I cannot get X11Forwarding to work when I login as the `ops` user.

```
ssh -X ops@ubuntu-bionic xclock

X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Error: Can't open display:
```

I want to be able to get it to work with the `ops` user. From the client, `$DISPLAY` has a value. When I login with `vagrant`, `$DISPLAY` has a value. When I login as `ops`, `$DISPLAY` is unset. If I set `$DISPLAY` to match what it is with the `vagrant` user, I get the same error:

```
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

when `X11UseLocalhost yes`

```
Error: Can't open display: ubuntu-bionic:10.0
```

when `X11UseLocalhost no`

If I login as `ops` and then `sudo su - vagrant`, `$DISPLAY` remains unset. If I login as `vagrant` and then `sudo su - ops`, `$DISPLAY` is inherited.

What am I missing to get this to work? I've run `xhost +` in each user (including `sudo -s root xhost +`) and it still doesn't work.

If I add `-vv` to my ssh commands, I see this message when connecting as `vagrant`:

```
X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
```

and as `ops`:

```
Remote: X11 forwarding disabled in user configuration file.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```